# How to compile my app with support library v7?

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am developing an app for min sdk 10. I want to add suppor library to my app and use it to provide actionbar for my app. How can support library for my app in eclipse.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First download Android Support Library from the SDK manager.
Then click on Import/Existing Code in workspace then select the location of your support library "SDK\extras\android\support\v7". And press ok.
Then right click on your project properties and go to Android tab and click on Add and select that file and click OK.

Answer (score 0):

*Firstly* you must download Android Supoort Library from the SDK manager.

Then add your respective support Library in **gradle** for the app like this, in the dependencies section :

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
```

}

Then **rebuild** your project or you may also directly **run** it.